# Is there a way to retrieve top 50 pages from facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

Is there a way that I can retrieve the top 50 (or 100) pages from facebook using php?

I read that api but it seems that I can retrive the pages of a certain user rather than pages in general.

Comment: visit http://www.facebook.com/pages/

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not entirely sure on what you mean when you say 'retrieve the top 50 (or 100) pages from facebook' so I'm going to assume you're talking about a search function.

The best place is [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/) under the heading 'Searching'.

What you do is get the json from https:// graph.facebook.com/search and then you add variables to the end of it. So if you wanted the 'stackoverflow' in facebook with it returning the top 100 'pages' (pages meaning no users, events, api's etc.. just pages created by facebook users) you would search

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=stackoverflow&type=page&limit=100
```

Do you see what I did?

I added the URL to graph then I said I was going to do a search then the search term is listed under q (query I presume) separated by the & symbol I added another condition being that the type of results would be pages (page) and the number of results published were limited to 100. You can change these by adding variables in position for each aspect.

Please tell me if you need me to build upon this any further.

Regards,

Jon

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I want is to retrieve the pages that have the most followers. See this link http://facebook.com/pages, pages are order in a descending order, is there a way to retrieve such information in json format for instance.

Comment: Hmmm... I've has a look to go however I can't seem to find a way with graph api (it's silly.. someone was able to take the url names 'likes' and 'browse'.. wtf! lol ). The only way I can see for 100% is either FQL or possibly (messy method) retrieving the data from actual page like that you provided. (all the top page data appears in one line so just get the html into an array for each line, then clean away the extra code that you don't want and explode it into another array. Messy but possible.)